# Why I can't drag to set contraint to barrier in Design view in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I am learning `ConstraintLayout` in Android Studio. I am following https://developer.android.com/codelabs/constraint-layout#10. After placing and setting the barrier, it said `2. Drag a constraint from the left side of cameraType to the barrier:`

However when I try it, it cannot detect contraint circle when dragging to barrier (as in photo below). I can only add contraint to barrier with adding line `app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/barrier"` in code view.

[Cannot detect contraint circle when dragging to barrier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upHtZ.jpg)

May I know the reason? Thanks a lot.